# Проверка формы с помощью JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Можете привести пример проверки формы, чтобы там проверялось мгновенно и по регулярным выражениям

Answer (score 2):

Проверка на наличие строки, содержащей пробелы

```
function validate() {
    var z = document.forms["test"]["text"].value;
    if (z != null && z != "") {
        if (/\s/.test(z)) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}

<form name="test" action="do.php" onsubmit="return validate();" method="post">
    <input type="text" name="text">
    <input type="submit" value="submit">
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Берите любую из [поиска](http://www.google.ru/#hl=ru&q=form+validation+javascript).